# Why is Livedata setValue ignored when called twice?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have the following ViewModel with MutableLiveData `data` and another LiveData `ones` that is derived from `data` in a way that it updates its value only if the `data.number` is equal to 1.

```
class DummyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val data = MutableLiveData<Dummy>()
    val ones = data.mapNotNull { it.takeIf { it.number == 1 } }

    init {
        data.value = Dummy(1, "Init")
        doSomething()

    }

    fun doSomething() {
        data.value = Dummy(2, "Do something")
    }
}

data class Dummy(val number: Int, val text: String)

fun <T, Y> LiveData<T>.mapNotNull(mapper: (T) -> Y?): LiveData<Y> {
    val mediator = MediatorLiveData<Y>()
    mediator.addSource(this) { item ->
        val mapped = mapper(item)
        if (mapped != null) {
            mediator.value = mapped
        }
    }
    return mediator
}
```

I observe `ones` in my fragment. However, If I execute `doSomething`, I don't receive any updates in my fragment. If I don't execute `doSomething`, the dummy `Init` is correctly present in `ones` and I receive an update.

What is happening here? Why is `ones` empty and how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What are you expecting of this `it.takeIf { it.number == 1 }` ?

Comment: @StanislavBondar I am expecting the `ones` LiveData to update its value only if the `number` property of the object is `1`. This is of course just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @StanislavBondar The issue that surprises me is the fact that the first `data.value = Dummy(1, "Init")` is not set if `doSomething` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but the behavior seems like expected to me...

Lets' try to reproduce both cases sequentially.

Without doSomething() :

1. Create `Livedata`
2. Add `Dummy(1, "Init")`
3. Start listening in the fragment: Because number is `1`, it passes your filter and the fragment receives it

With doSomething():

1. Create `Livedata`
2. Add `Dummy(1, "Init")`
3. Add `Dummy(2, "Do something")`  (`LiveData` keeps only the last value, so if nobody observes, the first value is getting lost)
4. Start listening in the fragment: Because number is `2`, the value gets filtered and the fragment receives nothing

A little offtopic: it's always good to write tests for ViewModel cases like this, because you'll be able to isolate the problem and find the real reason quickly.

EDIT: also be aware that your filter is only working on observing, it isn't applied when putting the value into `LiveData`.